# error loading page in $.mobile.changePage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi in my application I want to change page after succesfull login. On Login button click after validating user name and password I call next page as:

```
$.mobile.changePage('UI/demo/home.html')
```

But on click of Login button It validates data and when It tries to execute above line I got Error loading page message. As per I know it gets when page path is not correct But the same application run successfully on android and blackberry sumulator and when I tried it for nokia simulator, I got error loading message.

I call change Page from main.js which is in www/js folder and home page is in www/UI/demo folder.

If there is issue of path then how it works on android and blackberry platform?
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried with path `../UI/demo/home.html`, as you are in the `www/js` folder you need to go one level up

Comment: @dhaval yes I had tried that also

Answer (score 1):

If your login page is located in the www/UI/AppScreen/ folder and your home in the www/UI/demo folder then you should call:

```
$.mobile.changePage('../demo/home.html');
```

Or more in general

```
$.mobile.changePage('[RelativePath/]home.html');
```

The path is relative to your current HTML page.

Comment: my folder structure is like this:Login page is in:www/UI/AppScreen folder    Home page is in www/UI/demo folder.  From main.js I am calling changePage which is in  www/js folder.

Comment: If I use it as $.mobile.changePage('home.html');
  then it is not run on any platform not in android not in blackberry and neither in symbian

Comment: See the edit above for the different directory of the login page.

Comment: No luck after trying using your suggestion.

Comment: Could you try running your program in a computer browser (like Chrome) and use its debugger to see if and which javascript errors are popping up.

Answer (score 0):

For others reading this topic having trouble getting iOS to work:

If your pages are all in the same directory, prepending with ../ or / will not work, even though it works on the desktop.  You need to just use the page name, like 'home.html'.